# How do you handle CCPA Privacy Manager alert while running test cases in Selenium Webdriver/TestNG

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-strategy, debugging

When I run test cases in Selenium Webdriver or TestNG my test always fail.

The reason being, I'm not able to handle an alert-like pop-up exclusive to California residents. Those of you in California have seen this Privacy Manager pop-up. The window/alert/pop-up is part of the California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA).

It seems very simple, but I have tried handling it as an exception, as an alert, I've experimented with cookie settings as well. Please see the image below:

[image: Privacy Manager]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the CCPA Privacy Manager alert using the following steps in Selenium Webdriver/TestNG:

1 Locate the element of the pop-up using locators such as xpath, css selector, id, etc.

2 Once you locate the element, you can interact with it using Selenium Webdriver's WebElement class. For example, you can click the "Accept" or "Decline" button.

3 To dismiss the alert you can use the Alert interface of Selenium Webdriver, you can switch to the alert and either accept or dismiss it.

Example code in Java:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//element_locator")));
element.click();

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

4 If the pop-up is not a standard JavaScript alert, but is a modal window on the page, you can use WebDriverWait to wait for it to appear, and then interact with it using WebElement class.

Example code in Java:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//element_locator")));
element.click();
```

Note: Replace "element_locator" in the above code with the actual locator of the element you want to interact with.